# Как убрать обводку при клике на input

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, input

При клике и фокусе на элементе `input` появляется обводка. Как её убрать?

Comment: Кинь ссылку посмотреть на страничку

Comment: Ваша ссылка на изображение устарела, можете обновить?

Comment: focus-visible - рекомендую ознакомиться https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHg7DeciuW8

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
input {outline:none;}
```

Этот же приём убирает обводку пунктиром вокруг нажатой ссылки и вокруг любого из элементов формы.

Comment: {outline:none;} не работает в ие6-7

Comment: outline: none; border: none;

Answer (score 22):

Универсальное решение, которое убирает подсветку во всех браузерах и не только на `input`, но и на других элементах, в том числе `select`, `button`, `a`:

```
/* Remove outline on the forms and links */
:active, :hover, :focus {
    outline: 0;
    outline-offset: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте поставить `box-shadow: none;` 
У меня была такая проблема. Я просто сделал так при использовании Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Примените свойство `outline:none`

Answer (score 1):

У меня была такая проблема. Я просто сделал так:

```
input {outline: 0 !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для получения симпатичного белого поля для ввода используйте свойства `border` и `outline`.
Дополнительно рекомендую `border-radius`

```css
input {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Допишите также `onFocus="this.blur()"`

Comment: уже нельзя ничего навешивать на элементы, нужно цссом делать

Comment: А отдельным javascript'ом нельзя? Можно подключить скрипт и навесить события на нужные input'ы.
А под каким браузером мешает обводка?

Comment: Да скрипт помог справиться с файрфоксом и ие8, только теперь в ие6-7 обводка появляется вокруг тега label, а как ее убрать

Comment: Все, что могу предложить - перебрасывать фокус на какой-нибудь другой элемент. Примерно так (используя jQuery): $('checkbox, label').focusin(function(){$('#dummy').focus();});

Answer (score 0):

Если используете Bootstrap, то, возможно, используется `box-shadow`.

Попробуйте поставить `box-shadow: none;`

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно для `input` и конкретно при фокусе на нем:

```
input:focus {outline: 0;}
```

Проверял на Chrome.

Answer (score -3):

Физически обводку убрать никак нельзя, браузер сам ее рисует.
Фактически ее можно свернуть в точку, если у элемента A будет стиль не `display:block`, а `display:inline`. При этом на активную область это не повлияет, но это плохой вариант.

Лучше всего сделать элемент A поверх всей надписи, тогда заслонять надпись ничего не будет и выглядеть будет отлично.

Comment: к сожалению display:inline не помогает, и поверх надписи нельзя, хотят чтоб вообще не было, к том же в этом месте вверху есть чекбоксы которые не обводятся и работают нормально, а вот эти радиобаттоны обводятся везде даже в файрфоксе