# Неопознанный css-квадрат?

Tags: css

как убрать этот стиль квадрата,который появляется при нажатии на элемент(наблюдается в яндекс браузере,гугл хроме,мозиле)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, Вам стоит взглянуть на этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11307/html-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-input).

Решение:

```
:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: благодарю)