# Как убрать outline с тега details?

Tags: html, css

На теге `details` при клике в Safari и Chrome появляется обводка. На вид это обычный `outline`, однако через стили он не обнуляется:

```css
:active, :hover, :focus {
    outline: 0;
    outline-offset: 0;
}

details {
    outline: 0;
    outline-offset: 0;
}
```

```html
<details>
  Свой заголовок
  <p>Текст</p>
</details>
```

Как убрать эту обводку c `details`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как убрать обводку при клике на input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11307/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обводку вы убираете верно, но проблема в том, что вы невавилидно пишите разметку - заголовок должен быть обернут в тег `summary`, а он в свою очередь должен лежать непосредственно в `details`.

```css
:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Заголовок</summary>
  <p>Текст</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
summary {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: У меня в разметке нет summary.

Answer (score 1):

Там outline при focus

```css
details:focus,
summary:focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Свой заголовок</summary>
  <p>Текст</p>
</details>
```

Comment: У меня в разметке нет summary.

Comment: значит ваша разметка не верная ,

Comment: а без разметки "правильной" разметки реально сделать?

Comment: @webDev_ проголосовал за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

может так? :

```
details {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Я же написал, что outline: 0; неработает. А это значение - равнозначно.