# Как спрятать синие выделение в input`е

Tags: html, css

Как убрать синие полосы при вводе в input`е [image: вот эти]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как убрать обводку при клике на input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11307/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-input)

Answer (score 1):

В css напиши:

```css
input{outline:none;}
```